Запуск файла питон через Run Python File
Учусь работать в VScode.
Есть проблема с запуском файла python.
К моему проекту я создаю виртуальное окружение. Активирую его
Если запустить файл через командную строку
python main.py
то приложение заработает нормально.
Если же нажать на Run Python File
то создается новый терминал и программа запускается не из виртуального окружения
C:/Users/Сергей/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/my_app/character_creation_module/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\my_app\character_creation_module\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from graphic_arts.start_game_banner import run_screensaver
  File "c:\my_app\character_creation_module\graphic_arts\start_game_banner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from asciimatics.renderers import FigletText, Fire
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asciimatics'


Внизу справа в панели статуса (которая вдоль всего низа окна vscode идет) нажмите на версию Python и выберите интерпретатор из виртуального окружения. В целом, попробуйте открыть папку с программой, а не отдельный файл, теоретически в этом случае vscode может увидеть виртуальное окружение и предложить выбрать интерпретатор из него.
